# Why is the Black-White Bakery Algorithm considered bounded?

Tags: algorithms, concurrency, critical-section

As stated in Lamport's papers for the bakery algorithm he states that the ticket numbers are unbounded specifically

> The range of values of number is unbounded.

and

> Fortunately, practical considerations will place an 
>   upper bound on the value of *number*[i] in any real application. For example, if processors enter the doorway 
>   at the rate of at most one per msec, then after a year of 
>   operation we will have *number*[i] < $2^{35}$—assuming that 
>   a read of *number*[i] can never obtain a value larger than 
>   one which has been written there.

What I don't understand is, why does Taubenfeld's Black-White Bakery Algorithm solves this problem and thus considered bounded.

I see no reason why the usage of the extra color register would solve such a problem?

Thanks